# URL to open Find my friends

Tags: ios6

what's the URL to open Find my friends app on iOS?

I want to create an app that launches Apples find my friends (or the AppStore if its not installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handleopenurl.com has a vast amount of applications listed, also find my friends: http://handleopenurl.com/scheme/find-my-friends.